# How do I print on my frontend the result from a selected dropdown metabox (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

So, I've created a custom post type that have this metabox. The metabox is ok, but I'm not sure if it is saving right (I guess it is). Assuming that is all ok with this code (please, if there's anything wrong, tell me) I would like to know... **How do I show this day and month selected from my metabox in my front-end?**

(I don't know much about back-end and I'm trying to figure this out, sorry for any missunderstood)

Custom Post Type code:

```
function ccr_agenda() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        'add_new'             => _x( 'Add New Item', 'codexcoder', 'codexcoder' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'codexcoder' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit item', 'codexcoder' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'New item', 'codexcoder' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search in Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found in Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Agenda Trash', 'codexcoder' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'parent-item Agenda:', 'codexcoder' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Agenda', 'codexcoder' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'description'         => 'descrição',
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => null,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'supports'            => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'
            )
        );

    register_post_type( 'agenda', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
}

add_action( 'init', 'ccr_agenda' );
```

The metabox code:

```
// Agenda meta box register
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'agenda_metabox' );

function agenda_metabox($post){
    add_meta_box('agenda_metabox_id', 'Date event', 'show_agenda_metabox', '$post->post_type', 'side' , 'high');
}

// Saving Agenda data
add_action('save_post', 'ccr_agenda_save');

function ccr_agenda_save(){ 
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST["dia_agenda"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_agenda_dia = $_POST['dia_agenda'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', $meta_agenda_dia);
        //END OF UPDATE
    }

    if(isset($_POST["mes_agenda"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_agenda_mes = $_POST['mes_agenda'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', $meta_agenda_mes);
        //END OF UPDATE

    }
}

function show_agenda_metabox($post){
    $meta_agenda_dia = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', true); 

    $meta_agenda_mes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', true); 
    ?>   

    <label>Select a day:  </label>

    <select name="dia_agenda" id="dia_agenda">
      <option value="01" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '01' ); ?>>01</option>
      <option value="02" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '02' ); ?>>02</option>
// [ ... ]
      <option value="30" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '30' ); ?>>30</option>
      <option value="31" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '31' ); ?>>31</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <label>Select a month:  </label>

    <select name="mes_agenda" id="mes_agenda">
      <option value="01" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '01' ); ?>>jan</option>
// [... ]
      <option value="12" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '12' ); ?>>dec</option>
    </select>


    <?php
}
```

My front-end i'm trying to print the selected day and month like this:

```
<ul id="event-list">
    <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'agenda',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> 4,
        );

        $getPosts = new WP_Query($args);
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');

        while($getPosts->have_posts()) : $getPosts->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <span class="event">
                <h4 id="day"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'dia_agenda', true ); ?></h4>
                <h5 id="month"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'mes_agenda', true ); ?></h5>
            </span>

            <span class="sidebar-post-title"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile;
        remove_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');

    ?>                  
</ul>
```

But this code above it prints nothing on the screen. **So, I have 2 questions about this:**

1. What could I'm doing wrong? How could I get this right?
2. Once I get/printed the right results, How can I show it in this list/loop order by those results? (Like, the day&month more near to my current day will be displayed first on the list, and so on).

> I've searched about this but I didn't get any good results. Maybe it's
>   because I don't know much about back-end (like I said before), I'm just
>   trying to learn. (Consider this fact when you read this, pls :D)

---

### 1st UPDATE - (changes sugessted by @yivi)

I did the changes and the metabox is not displayed on my custom post type page anymore. Did I missing something here?

```
// Agenda meta box register
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'agenda_metabox' );

function agenda_metabox($post){
    add_meta_box('agenda_metabox_id', 'Date Event', 'show_agenda_metabox', '$post->post_type', 'side' , 'high');
}

// Saving Agenda data
add_action('save_post', 'ccr_agenda_save');

function ccr_agenda_save(){ 
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST["dia_agenda"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_agenda_dia = $_POST['dia_agenda'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'dia_agenda', $meta_agenda_dia);
        //END OF UPDATE
    }

    if(isset($_POST["mes_agenda"])){
         //UPDATE: 
        $meta_agenda_mes = $_POST['mes_agenda'];
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'mes_agenda', $meta_agenda_mes);
        //END OF UPDATE
    }
}

function show_agenda_metabox($post){
    $meta_agenda_dia = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dia_agenda', true); 

    $meta_agenda_mes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mes_agenda', true); 

 [...]
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? I don't understand your second question yet, but at least it should fix the more pressing matter of not actually displaying anything (and not saving the metas properly)

Comment: Hi @yivi! Yes, I did, thanks for helping! I replied your answer with some questions. About my second question... My frontend page shows something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOdUK.png the red squares show the day and month select. So I would like to order this list by this data, you know? Like a event list that show the netx events.

Comment: Your add_meta_box call is fishy. What are you using as your fourth parameter? You should be using "agenda".

Comment: It works!!!!!! Thank you si much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving your metas under the `show_agenda_metabox` , but you are trying to retrieve `dia_agenda` and `mes_agenda` keys.

You have this:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', $meta_agenda_dia);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', $meta_agenda_mes);
```

And then this:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'mes_agenda', true );
```

With the two "update_post_meta" you are actually overwriting your "day" meta with your "month" meta. So you should probably change that to something like:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'agenda_dia', $meta_agenda_dia);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'agenda_mes', $meta_agenda_mes);
```

And then use these calls, accordingly.

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'agenda_mes', true );
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'agenda_dia', true );
```

That should work.

(Also check that in your "month" select you are actually referring your "day" variable):

```
<select name="mes_agenda" id="mes_agenda">
  <option value="01" <?php selected( $meta_agenda_dia, '01' ); ?>>jan</option>
```

(Remember changing those `$meta_agenda_dia` with `$meta_agenda_mes`)

For sorting by these metas, check [WP_Query sorting docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), which allow you to sort by one of those metas; but WP doesn't allow natively to sort by more than meta. You can do it by using the `posts_orderby` filter, but it's probably a bit beyond your current skillset, at least right now.

Comment: But if I change this, I'll have to make a function for each field here:
function show_agenda_metabox($post){
    $meta_agenda_dia = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', true); //true ensures you get just one value instead of an array

    $meta_agenda_mes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_agenda_metabox', true); //true ensures you get just one value instead of an array
    ?> 

I mean, I have to change all "show_agenda_metabox" and specify for each one (dia_agenda & mes_agenda) ?

Comment: Trying to be more clear: You suggested that I make this change in my "ccr_agenda_save()" function, right? But what about those "show_agenda_metabox" on my "show_agenda_metabox($post)" function?

Comment: I was talking about changes both on storing and retrieving these metas. When you are saving them, you are doing it wrong (and losing one of the values). When you are retrieving your metas in your "show" function, you are specifying the wrong meta key: you are referring to "mes_agenda" and "dia_agenda" which are never saved (in your code). With my changes (both when saving and retrieving the data) you should be able to get the data.

Comment: just replace your `update_post_meta` with mine, and those `get_post_meta` with mine as well, and test it out. (you'll need to re-save your data in your wp admin, of course)

Comment: I did the change but my metabox  isn't showed anymore. See the update I did in this question, please. Did I do it wrong? About the "month" select, I have one doubt: this number after the variable $meta_agenda_mes is the same as the value or should I said it is "jan" for "jan" option, for example? (e.g.: <option value="01" <?php selected($meta_agenda_mes, 'jan');?>>jan</option>

Comment: Should be equal to the "value", since that is what you are actually saving to the DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131260/discussion-between-yivi-and-u23r).